# Varying TTL on LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, ping, icmp

I've got a wireless router behind a router-modem.

If I ping my router-modem (TWO hops), all seems well :

```
robut@host:~$ ping 172.X.X.36
PING 172.X.X.36 (172.X.X.36) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.X.X.36: icmp_seq=1 ttl=253 time=6.64 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.36: icmp_seq=2 ttl=253 time=5.08 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.36: icmp_seq=3 ttl=253 time=477 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.36: icmp_seq=4 ttl=253 time=7.97 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.36: icmp_seq=5 ttl=253 time=5.05 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.36: icmp_seq=6 ttl=253 time=5.02 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.36: icmp_seq=7 ttl=253 time=5.27 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.36: icmp_seq=8 ttl=253 time=5.58 ms
```

HOWEVER, if I ping the outside interface of the immediate wireless router (ONE hop), something f#!ky happens :
(I've marked some extreme anomalies.)

```
robut@host:~$ ping 172.X.X.37
PING 172.X.X.37 (172.X.X.37) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=0.564 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=2 ttl=65 time=1.17 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=3 ttl=65 time=0.623 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=4 ttl=65 time=0.609 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=5 ttl=116 time=0.969 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=6 ttl=44 time=4.11 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=7 ttl=65 time=0.993 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=8 ttl=65 time=4.35 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=9 ttl=44 time=23.8 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=10 ttl=44 time=0.736 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=11 ttl=44 time=0.685 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=12 ttl=116 time=3.75 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=13 ttl=116 time=4.63 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=14 ttl=116 time=71.2 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=15 ttl=116 time=387 ms <########
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=16 ttl=44 time=11.5 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=17 ttl=65 time=2.76 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=18 ttl=65 time=3.14 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=19 ttl=65 time=3.78 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=20 ttl=65 time=3.25 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=21 ttl=65 time=13.8 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=22 ttl=7 time=160 ms <########
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=23 ttl=65 time=97.8 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=24 ttl=65 time=2.40 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=25 ttl=116 time=12.9 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=26 ttl=44 time=0.687 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=27 ttl=44 time=1.62 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=28 ttl=116 time=0.658 ms <########
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=29 ttl=44 time=0.655 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=30 ttl=44 time=23.6 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=31 ttl=65 time=114 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=32 ttl=65 time=0.603 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=33 ttl=65 time=1.98 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=34 ttl=65 time=0.626 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=35 ttl=116 time=3.73 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=36 ttl=65 time=0.718 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=37 ttl=65 time=0.577 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=38 ttl=116 time=1.58 ms
```

Pinging the inside interface returns similar results. 
I'm connected wirelessly - will test wired tomorrow.

**UPDATE**
Tested wired. Similar nonsense (select lines) :

```
robut@host:~$ ping 172.X.X.37
PING 172.X.X.37 (172.X.X.37) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=1 ttl=44 time=0.219 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=111 ttl=13 time=0.235 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=112 ttl=5 time=0.247 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=113 ttl=13 time=0.218 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=114 ttl=5 time=0.260 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=133 ttl=65 time=0.227 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=134 ttl=5 time=0.205 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=135 ttl=44 time=0.233 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=136 ttl=67 time=0.204 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=137 ttl=44 time=0.197 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=138 ttl=67 time=0.204 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=139 ttl=44 time=0.182 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=140 ttl=65 time=0.165 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=141 ttl=44 time=0.188 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=142 ttl=65 time=0.223 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=212 ttl=5 time=0.242 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=213 ttl=80 time=0.193 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=214 ttl=5 time=0.204 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=233 ttl=44 time=0.195 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=234 ttl=50 time=0.178 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=235 ttl=44 time=0.182 ms
64 bytes from 172.X.X.37: icmp_seq=254 ttl=5 time=0.236 ms
```

So : What gives ?
Why is the TTL not 254 on all ICMP responses ?
Note that the TTL doesn't seem directly correlated with the time, since there's a "ttl=7 time=160 ms" but also "ttl=116 time=387 ms" and "ttl=116 time=0.658 ms".

Is my wireless router just a POS ?

Comment: Wow, that's crazy. I suspect your router is just a POS. It's probably not handling NAT-loopback (a.k.a. hairpin NAT) correctly, and trying to forward those pings off to its default gateway. But why the TTLs are all over the place and yet the pings all still get back to you (at least on the wireless side), I have no idea. If it was stuck in a forwarding loop, I'd expect them to stay stuck until they time out (TTL=0) and are dropped without ever making it back to you.

Comment: @Spiff Thanks for the reply. As mentioned, pinging the inside interface results in similar nonsense (TTL=44 most frequently, but I've seen 10, 111, 64). I tried disabling NAT (no other changes) and now I can't access the admin webpage (it redirects to /access_deny.htm, but that page 404s). So it seems like yeah, maybe the router wrongly routes/passes traffic to it's WAN interface, then back in, even for LAN stuff. Despite this, I can still ping the router's inside interface with NAT off ... and now I've seen TTLs of 255 returned. @_@

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, which you say is ok, there is a delayed response as well even though the TTL is the same as the other pings so it looks like you have a random delay somewhere.

64 bytes from 172.X.X.36: icmp_seq=3 ttl=253 time=477 ms

However the variable TTL's seem to suggest you have a routing problem somewhere

I'd run a traceroute (or tracert on Windows) to try to see where your pings are actually going